# Erro ao transportação dados excel para python - formato data

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-excel

Meu código consiste em puxar informações de um arquivo de Excel e transportá-los para um banco de dados através de Python.
Porém em campos do tipo data (formatados no próprio Excel) ao importar os dados eles são formatos para tipo texto onde o valor é a diferença entre a data atual e 01/01/1900 (função data.valor do Excel).
Alguém conhece um modo de exportar a data corretamente sem ter que formatar a tabela na mão?

*OBS: eu já tentei mudar o tipo do campo na planilha, mas ao realizar isso ela volta para o tipo dias corridos.

A primeira imagem mostra como os dados vem:

[image: Como a data é mostrada numa planilha sem tratamento]

Na segunda imagem, na primeira célula é a data com formatação "data" a segunda é o mesmo valor com a formatação 'geral"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Suellen, você não está informando como você está pegando os dados do Excel, você está usando alguma biblioteca? É importante adicionar o código do que você tentou na sua pergunta para que seja mais fácil te ajudarem.

Comment: Você tem que usar a função `=Eval()` do Python para pegar **exatamente** o que está sendo enviado, no caso a data. Porém, como disse o Fernando, sem o código fica impossível te ajudar além disso

Comment: Se você não tiver certeza do que está fazendo **NUNCA** use `eval()` de linguagem nenhuma. Seu problema é outro, o Excel guarda datas como inteiros representando o número de dias ocorrido desde 01/01/1900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Excel, datas são guardadas como inteiros que representam quantos dias se passaram desde o dia 01/01/1900.

Se fosse simples assim bastaria criarmos a data inicial e somarmos os dias com um [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

# código ERRADO    
def converte_data_excel(qtde_dias):
    data_inicial = date(1900, 1, 1)
    return data_inicial + timedelta(days=qtde_dias)

dias = [0, 1, 60, 42_005, 43_663]

for dia in dias:
    data = converte_data_excel(dia)
    print(f"{dia:>5}: {data:%d/%m/%Y}")
```

<sup>Código "funcionando" no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-397932-6333-a)</sup>

---

Mas nem tudo são rosas, a saída do código anterior é:

```
    0: 01/01/1900
    1: 02/01/1900
   60: 02/03/1900
42005: 03/01/2015
43663: 19/07/2019
```

Usando o Excel online coloquei os valores inteiros em uma coluna e na outra o inteiro é convertido para data pelo próprio Excel:

[image: Dados do Excel]

---

Temos dois problemas aqui:

1. O primeiro é que o inteiro não é exatamente o número dias desde 01/01/1900, pois se fosse, o número 0 representaria o dia 01/01/1900 e não o dia 02/01/1900, pois nenhum dia se passou de 01/01/1900 até 01/01/1900. E estranhamente quando se converte o número zero para data no Excel a data é mostrada como 00/01/1900 (vai entender).

   Então a primeira correção a ser feita é diminuir 1 da quantidade de dias para compensar essa bizarrice, ou diminuir um dia da  `data_inicial` pelo mesmo motivo.

   ```
   data_inicial = date(1899, 12, 31)
   ```
2. O segundo problema é que o Excel considera que 1900 foi um [ano bissexto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ano_bissexto), porém isso não é verdade. Anos terminado em "00" só são bissextos se forem divisíveis por 400, e não é este o caso.

   Por isso é necessário compensar este dia decrementando em 1 a quantidade de dias do valor se este for maior ou igual a 60.

   ```
   if qtde_dias >= 60:
       qtd_dias -= 1
   ```

---

Com estes detalhes corrigidos, o código agora é capaz de converter corretamente os valores inteiros recebidos da planilha:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def converte_data_excel(qtde_dias):
    data_inicial = date(1899, 12, 31)

    if qtde_dias >= 60:
        qtde_dias -= 1

    return data_inicial + timedelta(days=qtde_dias)

dias = [0, 1, 60, 42_005, 43_663]

for dia in dias:
    data = converte_data_excel(dia)
    print(f"{dia:>5}: {data:%d/%m/%Y}")
```

<sup>Código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-397932-6333-b)</sup>

Agora a saída é:

```
    0: 31/12/1899
    1: 01/01/1900
   60: 28/02/1900
42005: 01/01/2015
43663: 17/07/2019
```

Lembrando que o dia 29/02/1900 não existiu, se você realmente quiser replicar esse valor no python vai precisar tratar de alguma outra maneira, seja retornando `None`, lançando uma exceção ou o que achar melhor.